Why does $\langle x | f \rangle = f(x) $?
i am trying to understand why does $\langle x | f \rangle = f(x) $.
My line of thought so far:
we will write $f_n(x)$ as the discrete approximation of $f(x)$, where $f_n(x)$ is given by $| f_n \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} f_n(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f_n(x_n) \end{pmatrix} $, $| x_i \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $, $|f_n\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_n(x_i) \ |x_i\rangle$, and $f_n(x_i)=\langle x_i|f_n\rangle$. So we can now say that if we take an infinite number of points, we get $|f\rangle $ as an infinite series, and $|x\rangle $ is also an infinite column vector which when applied to $f$ will give us only its value at $x$ (i.e. $f(x)$), as did $|x_i\rangle$ with $|f_n\rangle$.
Is this line of thought correct? could you make it more precise and formal?

I don’t do much quantum mechanics but from what I do know that’s just by definition; $|f\rangle=\sum_xf(x)|x\rangle$ by definition, no?

Although I have seen an approach where we take this as the definition, Shankar doesn't seem to say it is a definition, but rather a result of the discrete reasoning above. Also, my professor derived it completely differently and did not take it as a definition.

In that case I’m not sure how to proceed. At least the way I was taught it was taken to be a definition and what you’re describing was derived from there.

Your derivation seems completely correct to me. Though I dare not declare it mathematically rigorous, your intuition is certainly correct

The $i$-th component of vector $\vec{v}$ can be written as either $v_i$, or $\vec{v} \cdot \hat{e}_i$, where $\hat{e}_i$ is a unit vector pointing in the $i$-th direction. So you can say $v_i = \hat{e}_i \cdot \vec{v}$. The equation $f(x) = \langle x | f \rangle$ is completely analogous to this, just that we are using an infinite dimensional (rigged) Hilbert space instead of a 'normal' vector space.

Its a definition.

This question is similar to: Understanding Dirac's notation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In Shankar's book, the point is to determine the components of $|\psi\rangle$ in the position basis. If we label the components as $\psi(x)$, then we want
$$|\psi\rangle=\int\psi(x')|x'\rangle\ \text dx'$$
Since $\langle x|x'\rangle=\delta(x'-x)$, we get
$$\langle x|\psi\rangle=\int\psi(x')\langle x|x'\rangle\ \text dx'=\psi(x)$$
But I think this is kind of circular, or at least there are different "points of entry". If we say $\langle x|\psi\rangle$ will always pick out the "x component" of $|\psi\rangle$, and this will be a function of $x$, so we label it as $\psi(x)$ for clarity. In other words.... if we set up the notation $\langle x|\psi\rangle$ to be the "x component" of $|\psi\rangle$ understood to be this linear combination, then it kind of just falls out if we assume a orthonormal position basis.

Thank you. Maybe i am wrong, but shankar derived <x|x'>=delta from <x|f>=f(x), but other than that i agree with everything you have written.

@R24698 Yeah that is what I was trying to say about things being "circular". You can start with one and get to the other. It depends on your starting point.

I have seen your edit after sending the comment, thank you!
